# Split nested JSON file which has multiple records in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

So I have this NDJSON file which has thousands of records and the records are nested as well. Since the files are very large(~150mb) I want to split them into two files but am having issues splitting the files in half (doesn't need to be exactly half). I get the error message: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Sample of my NDJSON file

```
{
  "time": "2023-02-28T23:28:01.295231Z",
  "resourceId": "asdf",
  "operationName": "Sign-in activity",
  "operationVersion": "1.0",
  "category": "Category"
  "resultDescription": null,
  "timestampZulu": "2023-03-08T00:05:31.495000Z",
  "timestampSeconds": 1678233931,
  "properties": {
    "alternateSignInName": null,
    "appServicePrincipalId": null,
    "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "displayName": "Guest User Access",
        "enforcedGrantControls": [
          "Guest Access Terms of Use"
        ],
        "enforcedSessionControls": [
          "SignInFrequency"
        ],
        "result": "notApplied",
        "conditionsSatisfied": 1,
        "conditionsNotSatisfied": 2
      },
      {
        "id": "123",
        "displayName": "Restricted",
        "enforcedGrantControls": [
          "Block"
        ],
        "enforcedSessionControls": [],
        "result": "notApplied",
        "conditionsSatisfied": 0,
        "conditionsNotSatisfied": 1
      }
    ],
    "authenticationContextClassReferences": [],
    "authenticationDetails": [],
    "authenticationProcessingDetails": [
      {
        "key": "adsf",
        "value": "False"
      }
      {
        "key": "ABC",
        "value": "False"
      }
    ],
    "authenticationProtocol": "none",
    "authenticationRequirement": "singleFactorAuthentication",
    "authenticationRequirementPolicies": [],
    "authenticationStrengths": [],
    "autonomousSystemNumber": 20115,
    "crossTenantAccessType": "none",
    "deviceDetail": {
      "isCompliant": false,
      "isManaged": false,
      "operatingSystem": "Windows 10"
    }
  }
}
  .... multiple records that is similar
```

Python Script
I tried both by specifying the number of records and by splitting in half. I also thought it had to do with the nested json so I tried to flatten and normalized it but no luck

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
   
    # Read the contents of the JSON file from S3
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)
    #contents = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    contents = response['Body']
    data = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in response['Body'].iter_lines())
    for row in data:
        json_data = json.loads(row)
        # df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
        # flat_df = pd.json_normalize(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
        # flat_json = flat_df.to_json(orient='records')
   
    chunks = [json_data[i:1 + 2000] for i in range(0, len(json_data), 2000)]
   
    destination_prefix = 'split-files/'
   
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chunk_key = destination_prefix + f'split-{i}.json'
        chunk_content = json.dumps(chunk)
        s3.put_object(Bucket=destination_json_curated_bucket, Key=chunk_key, Body=chunk_content)
        
    return f'{len(chunks)} chunks created'
   
    # Split the JSON data in half
    # length = len(json_data)
    # print(f"Length = {length}")
    # half = length // 2
    # print(f"half = {half}")
    # first_half = json_data[:half]
    # second_half = json_data[half:]
```

Comment: If it's a JSON file, all the records should be inside a list `[{...}, {...}, ...]`. You need to read the whole thing, then you can split up the list and write each chunk to different files.

Comment: Sorry it's an NDJSON File

Comment: You have `json_data[i:1 + 2000]`. Did you mean `json_data[i:i + 2000]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of minor fixes to row accumulation and iteration:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

destination_json_curated_bucket = "mybucket"


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    source_bucket = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]

    # Read the contents of the JSON file from S3
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)

    # contents = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    data = (line.decode("utf-8") for line in response["Body"].iter_lines())
    json_data = []

    for row in data:
        json_data.append(json.loads(row))

    chunks = [json_data[i : i + 2000] for i in range(0, len(json_data), 2000)]

    destination_prefix = "split-files/"

    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chunk_key = f"{destination_prefix}/split-{i}.json"
        chunk_content = json.dumps(chunk)
        s3.put_object(
            Bucket= destination_json_curated_bucket, Key=chunk_key, Body=chunk_content
        )

    return f"{len(chunks)} chunks created"
```

Comment: Ok I think that worked. I need to look more into it. So it created 11 json files so to reduce that number to 2 files, I'll probably need to increase the number 2000 to a higher number?

Comment: Yes, for N files replace 2000 with something like `math.ceil(len(json_data) / N)`

Comment: Thank You! that worked, it split the file into two. The only other issue I'm having is when I try to view the split file in AWS Console in S3 Bucket using Query with S3 Select I get the error message: The character number in one record is more than our max threshold, maxCharsPerRecord: 1,048,576. I'm still looking into it